# Truncate delta table in Databricks using python

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Delta table delete operation is given [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-python) for Python and SQL, and truncate using SQL is given [here](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-truncate-table.html). But I cannot find the documentation for Python truncate table.

How to do it for delta table in Databricks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not everything is exposed as a function for Python or Java/Scala.  Some operations are SQL-only, like `OPTIMIZE` for example.  If you want to truncate table, you have two choices:

1. Use

```
spark.sql("TRUNCATE TABLE <name>")
```

or

```
spark.sql("TRUNCATE TABLE delta.`<path>`")
```

2. Emulate truncate with read + write empty dataframe in overwrite mode:

```py
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("<path>")
df.limit(0).write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").save("<path>")
```